# Please help me debug my code in R for finding odd and even

Tags: r, if-statement, debugging

```
x <- (readline(prompt = "Enter number :" ))
 as.numeric(x) 
 if(x%% 2 ==0) {
 print("x is even")
 } else {
 print("x is odd") 
 }
```

Error in x%%2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: It would be a good idea to share the error message or other problems like undesired result, and how you tried to debug your code.

Comment: Error: unexpected symbol in:
"} else {
  print("x"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't assign the return value of `as.numeric` to `x` for the following `if...else...` statement.

You can try the code below, which should work as you expected:

```
x <- as.numeric(readline(prompt = "Enter number :"))
if (x %% 2 == 0) {
  print("x is even")
} else {
  print("x is odd")
}
```

Comment: after using this code it displays an error message : Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Comment: where is the error? I am unable to find it